# Make Liferay 7 popup fill value in underlying form

Tags: javascript, forms, popup, liferay-7

I have a Liferay portlet which has a form (normal `<form>` but I could change it to `<aui:form>`).

This form has a read-only text input field (let's say `fruit`) and a link that opens a popup that lets the user choose a fruit.

From the popup, how to modify the `fruit` field's value in the underlying form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a good approach is using events.

You need to listen to an event in form page and trigger that event from popup.

form page :

```
Liferay.on('eventName', function(e){
  //e.selectedFruit
});
```

in popup :

```
Liferay.fire('eventName', {selectedFruit: 'orange'});
```

Of course you need to choose event name carefully preventing conflict.

For example you can add portlet namespace prepend it and send that event name as a parameter to popup.

Answer (score 0):

You can use liferay alloy UI for same.
This tutorial might help 
https://alloyui.com/examples/color-picker/popover

Comment: I wrote "let's say" because color was just an example. Sorry I will choose a more abstract example.